# Does higher tax encourage high economic gowth?

Tags: macroeconomics, economic-growth

[image]

Text in image:

Which of the following is LEAST likely to be associated with a higher rate of economic growth?

(A) strong protection of property rights

(B) taxes on savings and investment

(C) policies that discourage immigration

(D) higher consumption

(E) encouraging the replenishment of natural resources

According to me, the answer should be (B). Taxes on investment will lead to lower economic growth, since $$\operatorname{rGDP} = C + I + G + XN$$ and more $I$, more economic growth.

Economic growth (for the purpose for High School Macroeconomics) means a right shift in PPC, so less investment, less innovation etc.

Can someone explain? Thanks

Comment: This question is similar to a recent question.

Comment: I believe taxes can feed both C, I and G. The government can make investments. And when it pays social security, that feeds back to consumers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the short term, this year's GDP. It is possible that investment results in a higher GDP later on, in subsequent years.

Since both investment and savings are taxed, people are not disincentivized from investing. However, if you people consume instead of investing then while this years GDP is unchanged, the GDP in subsequent years might be lower.

---

The question is a poor one though.

I would also have thought that they meant (B), because unless you notice that savings are also taxed, this seems like a textbook free markets question.

Also, the phenomena are not very detailed, thus assigning any likelihood is difficult.

Comment: Hi @Giskard, Thank you for the answer. Option (C) also seems confusing. (For High School Macroeconomics), Won't discouraging immigration lead to slower economic growth?

Comment: Indeed. As I wrote, without details assigning any likelihood is difficult.